# Grouping/Sectioning a Many-to-Many Relationship in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, join

Is there a way to establish a Many-to-Many relationship using a join table in Hibernate that uses a column in the join table to determine if an item belongs in the relationship?

Also, is it possible to specify the ordering of the related items by a key in the join table (as opposed to a key in the destination table)?

Let's say I have User and TVShow tables, and a UserShow join table. I want my users to have multiple categories of shows (let's say, "cable" and "broadcast"). One way to define this would be to add a "category int" column to the UserShow join table, and then the join query can have a WHERE clause that specifies which category. I didn't see anything in the @JoinTable or @JoinColumn annotations that would allow me to qualify the join.

Similarly for ordering, the UserShow join table has a "sequence int" column that specifies the order in which a User's shows should appear. All the examples of @OrderBy suggest it uses destination table columns.

EDIT:

Here are the tables I propose:

```
create table User
(
    mId         integer         auto_increment primary key not null,
);

create table TVShow
(
    mId         integer         auto_increment primary key not null,
    mName       varchar(128)    not null,
);

create table UserShow
(
    mId         integer         auto_increment  primary key not null,
    mUserId     integer         not null,
    mShowId     integer         not null,
    mCategory   integer         default 0,
    mSequence   integer         default 0,

    constraint cUserShowUser  foreign key (mUserId) references User(mId),
    constraint cUserShowShow  foreign key (mShowId) references TVShow(mId)
);
```

I'd like to be able to get all the TVShows for a user for mCategory = 1, in mSequence order, and separately get all the TVShows for a user for mCategory = 2, in mSequence order.

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Proxy(lazy = true)
public
class
User implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public  Long                getId()                                     { return mId; }
    public  void                setId(Long inVal)                           { mId = inVal; }

    public  List<TVShow>        getShows()                                  { return mShows; }
    public  void                setShows(List<TVShow> inVal)                { mShows = inVal; }

    public  void                addShow(TVShow inShow)                      { getShows().add(inShow); }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long                mId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {})
    @JoinTable(name = "UserShow",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mUserId"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mShowId"))
    @OrderBy("mName asc")
    private List<TVShow>        mShows;

    private static  Logger  sLogger                         =   Logger.getLogger(User.class);
}
```

TVShow.java:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Proxy(lazy = true)
public
class
TVShow implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public  Long                getId()                                     { return mId; }
    public  void                setId(Long inVal)                           { mId = inVal; }

    public  String              getName()                                   { return mName; }
    public  void                setName(String inVal)                       { mName = inVal; }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long                mId;

    private static  Logger      sLogger                         =   Logger.getLogger(TVShow.class);
}
```

Comment: What you want is not clear, can you be more specific on what tables you want, and how they need to be related.

Comment: I'll be more specific on what's not clear. You say user can have multiple categories of shows, are the categories the primary key of the tv show table. Secondly, explain in what way a tv show needs a many relationship with user. Lastly does your join table need to contain other information besides the relationship mapping?

Comment: I've edited the post to show the tables I propose. 1) The categories are just a way of classifying joined shows. 2) The many relationship for TVShow->User allows me to ask, "Which users like this show?" I also added a bit more about what I'd like to get out of it.

Comment: This should get you what you want                     http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: Hmm, that's not quite what I have or am looking for. For one thing, I only have Java objects for User and TVShow. I added my classes. I just want to add a method on User "getShows(int inCagetgory)" or even "getCategory1Shows()" and "getCategory1Shows()".

Comment: If you want extra columns on your join table you have to create a java class for it no way around it

Comment: Okay, I don't mind creating the class, but I still don't see how I can create a relationship from User to TVShow that effectively adds a "WHERE" clause to the join table.

Comment: select distinct User from UserShow list
where list.Show.category = 1; in short once your entities are bound the selection criteria is not defined in your table setup